# `for` loop to avoid writing same thing multiple times

Tags: c++, for-loop

```cpp
    const double weight1{result["w_group_1"]};
    std::string weight_bar1;
    GetData(weight1, weight_bar1);
    weight_bar1 += " ";  

    const double weight2{result["w_group_2"]};
    std::string weight_bar2;
    GetData(weight2, weight_bar2);
    weight_bar2 += " ";  
    
    const double weight3{result["w_group_3"]};
    std::string weight_bar3;
    GetData(weight3, weight_bar3);
    weight_bar3 += " ";
```

How to avoid writing same thing 3 times with different numbers? If it was a variable in some calculation which has some min and max, I could have used simple `for` loop. But this is different.

Comment: Instead of `weight1`, `weight2`, `weight3`, etc., you can have something like a `std::vector<double> weights;` and then access `weights[0]`, `weights[1]`, `weights[2]` and so on. Similarly for `weight_bar#`. A little trickier to automatically generate the `"w_group_#"` strings as necessary, however.

Comment: The only thing that is different, as far as I can tell, is the key to `result`, which differs by the ending number; so you can concatenate a number to the end of it to get the key you want.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. What is `result`?

Comment: Instead of using a loop to reduce the repetition, you could write a function that you call with different arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC those elements are called associative arrays. Those are not allowed in C++. C++ has `std::map` to facilitate such a thing.

```
std::map<std::string,int> result;

result["abcd"] = 55;
```

to achieve number after string use `std::to_string(<number>)`

so to put it in your code:

```
std::string name ("w_group");
std::string nameNum;
for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
   nameNum = name + std::to_string(i);
   const double weight{result[name]};
   std::string weight_bar;
   GetData(weight, weight_bar);
   weight_bar += " "; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a typo in first code block. _reslut_ should be _result_